# The woman tries to dial again, but the phone is dead

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Context: A burglar has cut the phone line of a house. Inside the house a woman was talking on a landline phone when the line was cut.

Then -

**The woman tries to dial again, but the phone is dead.**

Is this correct and logically phrased in the context?

Answer (score 1):

The phone being dead does not prevent the woman from actually dialling, so it is not the dialling itself that she "tries" to do. It is getting results from dialling again that is fruitless.

Perhaps:

"The woman tries to reconnect by dialling again, but the line is dead."

Comment: Whether you can dial or not depends on the phone system really (and whether *dialling* means "pressing the buttons / spinning the wheel" or the overall process of sending the commands to the network and getting a connection) but really, I think the OP's example reads fine and makes the point! I don't think it's the kind of writing that benefits from technical accuracy, y'know? Keep it tense and snappy

Comment: @cactustictacs Fair enough, a good point well-made. But in my defence, the question was whether it was correct and logically phrased, not whether it was adequate for a crimefic pot-boiler. For the record, however "dialling" *does* mean "pressing the buttons / spinning the wheel". When you have finished dialling, that's when you get the connection or not. As it stands, the sentence unfortunately comes across as having been written with little thought -- and this is a site to teach good English, not how to write cheap novels.